# Swing GUI not showing Error but not running

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple login form that compiles and does not show any compile or build errors but does not show up an interface when i try to run it. I have checked and set 'setVisible(true)' but still no luck.
I am not exactly sure what the problem is but any help will be appreciated. I am using Netbeans IDE.
Here is the source code.

```
package client.system;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class LoginForm extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    /**
     * Creates new form LoginForm
     */
    public LoginForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        username = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        password = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        login = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Log In");

        jLabel2.setLabelFor(username);
        jLabel2.setText("Username:");

        username.setText("Username");

        jLabel3.setLabelFor(password);
        jLabel3.setText("Password:");

        password.setText("Password");

        login.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        login.setText("Login");
        login.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                loginActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 283, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(username))
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 283, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))
                        .addGap(0, 43, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(70, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String sql="select * from login where username=? and password=?";
        try{
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testsql","root","mysql");
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, username.getText()); 
            pst.setString(2,password.getText());
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"username and password matched");
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Username or Password");
            }
        }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
        }
    }                                     
    public static void main(String args[]){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new LoginForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JButton login;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField password;
    private javax.swing.JTextField username;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on swing but two questions. One, is this class being called anytime? And Two, I remember that in order to show a panel, it should be contained inside a frame, right?

Comment: It looks life you are generating the form with NetBeans. Create a new JFrame form and call it LoginFrame or something similarly relevant. Set the layout manager to BorderLayout. Then drag your LoginForm file onto the LoginFrame panel in the middle. It should fill the frame. Right click on LoginFrame and press "Run File".

Comment: You are both right, I got it working. @Campbell, Please write your comment as an answer in such a way that may help others so that i may mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If the form/JPanel was generated using NetBeans

Create a new JFrame Form. Drag your JPanel Form from the project window onto the newly created JFrame Form. You have to do this, because a JPanel requires a JFrame root parent to be visible on the screen. It does not have any window logic.

### If you did not create the form/JPanel using NetBeans

Create a new JFrame and add the form/JPanel to it as a child. Here is a very simple example for how you could potentially achieve this:

```
public class ExampleFrame extends JFrame {

    public ExampleFrame() {
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        setTitle("My Cool Custom Panel");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExampleFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```